# Appending Record from Form to Table with VB

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I've read a few Q&A's regarding this and I think I understand it however in true amature style I think I'm missing something here.

What I'm trying to do is to display one record at a time in a form from table 'A' and give the user an option of pressing a button so they can append the currently viewed record to Table 'B' using the VB code below. however when I press the button nothing happens, could somebody please help me clarify whether I have understood what I have read correctly:

Private Sub Command31_Click()

```
Dim PartNo, TotalQty, Description, Manufacturer, TotalCost, Category, Warehouse, BinLoc, OrderNum, DateRec, UnitCost, ReturnCode, Batch, bookinsql
PartNo = Form_LiveQfrm.[PartNo]
TotalQty = Form_LiveQfrm.[TotalQty]
Description = Form_LiveQfrm.[Description]
Manufacturer = Form_LiveQfrm.[Manufacturer]
TotalCost = Form_LiveQfrm.[TotalCost]
Category = Form_LiveQfrm.[Category]
Warehouse = Form_LiveQfrm.[Warehouse]
BinLoc = Form_LiveQfrm.[BinLoc]
OrderNum = Form_LiveQfrm.[OrderNum]
DateRec = Form_LiveQfrm.[DateRec]
UnitCost = Form_LiveQfrm.[UnitCost]
ReturnCode = Form_LiveQfrm.[ReturnCode]
Batch = Form_LiveQfrm.[Batch]
bookinsql = "INSERT INTO QStore (TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, TextField, TextField, DateField, NumericField, TextField, NumericField ) VALUES ('" & Form_LiveQfrm.PartNo & "', " & Form_LiveQfrm.TotalQty & ", '" & Form_LiveQfrm.Description & "', '" & Form_LiveQfrm.Manufacturer & "', " & Form_LiveQfrm.TotalCost & ", '" & Form_LiveQfrm.Category & "', '" & Form_LiveQfrm.Warehouse & "', '" & Form_LiveQfrm.BinLoc & "', '" & Form_LiveQfrm.OrderNum & "', #" & Form_LiveQfrm.DateRec & "#, " & Form_LiveQfrm.UnitCost & ", '" & Form_LiveQfrm.ReturnCode & "', " & Form_LiveQfrm.Batch & ");"

DoCmd.RunSQL bookinsql

End Sub
```

My LiveQTemp Table is layed out like this:

```
ID - AutoNumber
PartNo - Text
TotalQty - Number
Description Text
Manufacturer - Text
TotalCost - Number
Category - Text
Warehouse - Text
BinLoc - Text
OrderNum - Text
DateRec - Date/Time
UnitCost - Number
ReturnCode - Text
Batch - Number
```

Comment: Does it give any errors?

Comment: also I noticed you do not have `'` around your `textfield`s.  You kinda had things backward in yours, strings get `'` and numbers get nothing and dates get `#` around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your statement just before the word `VALUES` in your column specifications.

Change this:

```
bookinsql = "INSERT INTO LiveQTemp (TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, TextField, NumericField, DateField, NumericField, TextField, NumericField,  ) VALUES (" & PartNo & ", '" & TotalQty & "', " & Description & ", " & Manufacturer & ", '" & TotalCost & "', " & Category & ", " & Warehouse & ", " & BinLoc & ", '" & OrderNum & "', '" & DateRec & "', '" & UnitCost & "', " & ReturnCode & ", '" & OrderNum & "');"
```

To this:

```
bookinsql = "INSERT INTO LiveQTemp (TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, NumericField, TextField, TextField, TextField, NumericField, DateField, NumericField, TextField, NumericField) VALUES ('" & PartNo & "', " & TotalQty & ", '" & Description & "','" & Manufacturer & "', " & TotalCost & ", '" & Category & "','" & Warehouse & "','" & BinLoc & "',' " & OrderNum & "', #" & DateRec & "#, " & UnitCost & ",'" & ReturnCode & "', " & Batch & ");"
```

Also if you are not getting errors, it is probably because warning are set to off via: 
`docmd.setwarnings = false` and you should turn them back on after running statments via `docmd.setwarnings = true`.  If you are testing something new I would leave them on until it is validated and then turn it to false during the statment, just make sure you turn it back on afterwards.

Edit:

You keep changing your orginal question with updated information and you should not do that, you should only add new information it confuses other and the people trying to help.

Here is the entire function you need:

```
Private Sub Command31_Click()

    Dim PartNo, TotalQty, Description, Manufacturer, TotalCost, Category, Warehouse, BinLoc, OrderNum, DateRec, UnitCost, ReturnCode, Batch, bookinsql
    PartNo = Me.[PartNo]
    TotalQty = Me.[TotalQty]
    Description = Me.[Description]
    Manufacturer = Me.[Manufacturer]
    TotalCost = Me.[TotalCost]
    Category = Me.[Category]
    Warehouse = Me.[Warehouse]
    BinLoc = Me.[BinLoc]
    OrderNum = Me.[OrderNum]
    DateRec = Me.[DateRec]
    UnitCost = Me.[UnitCost]
    ReturnCode = Me.[ReturnCode]
    Batch = Me.[Batch]
    bookinsql = "INSERT INTO LiveQTemp (PartNo , TotalQty , Description , Manufacturer , TotalCost , Category , Warehouse , BinLoc , OrderNum , DateRec , UnitCost , ReturnCode , Batch ) VALUES ('" & PartNo & "', " & TotalQty & ", '" & Description & "', '" & Manufacturer & "', " & TotalCost & ", '" & Category & "', '" & Warehouse & "', '" & BinLoc & "', '" & OrderNum & "', #" & DateRec & "#, " & UnitCost & ", '" & ReturnCode & "', " & Batch & ");"
  '                              ^
  '                              |
  '                             Change this table to whatever table you are trying to put it in, you have listed two different ones

    DoCmd.RunSQL bookinsql

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting this @ObieMD5 , unfortunatly this has not solved my problem.

Comment: @bikerben can update your qestion with the table layout for LiveQTemp

Comment: @bikerben I dunno if `numericfield` is describing the datatype in the table, if it is then you do not need `'` around the item, and dates need `#` around them. I have updated my answer.  Also did you know you have OrderNum in your table twice?

Comment: I'll give this a whirle @ObieMD5, thank you. I did notice that my slq statement did not reflect exactly what my fields were too. Let me make the changes and I'll keep you posted. Thank you again for your input, it is really appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my slq statement and adjusted it so all the syntax is correct as you have mentioned including having the OrderNum as a repeated field. I noticed that I Access turned off some features because it thought one of the databases was insecure. These are no turn on and I now get Runtime error 424 which points to this line of code "PartNo = LiveQfrm.[PartNo]". Just to clarify LiveQfrm is the form the button and the current record are displayed on. I'm sorry this is'nt as clean cut as we would like @ObieMD5

Comment: @bikerben Check the edit section of my post. You are calling your objects wrong.

Comment: Thank you @ObieMD5 I have adjusted this and noticed the sql statement required this format as well, I've updated my the statement to reflect this but I still get a "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement" when I press the button. I'm feel like I'm a little out of my depth here. I've looked at a few more examples on the net and they look very much like mine but I don't understand why it will not run. :(

Comment: Look at my edit section above you should be able to copy and paste the entire function only thing is to change the table name in the insert statement if you need to.